# Circular Buffer in Flash

Tags: embedded, queue, circular-buffer, flash-memory

I need to store items of varying length in a circular queue in a flash chip.  Each item will have its encapsulation so I can figure out how big it is and where the next item begins.  When there are enough items in the buffer, it will wrap to the beginning.

**What is a good way to store a circular queue in a flash chip?**

There is a possibility of tens of thousands of items I would like to store.  So starting at the beginning and reading to the end of the buffer is not ideal because it will take time to search to the end.

Also, because it is circular, I need to be able to distinguish the first item from the last.

The last problem is that this is stored in flash, so erasing each block is both time consuming and can only be done a set number of times for each block.

Comment: I'm confused by your language. A buffer, in my mind, is a fast, volatile piece of memory that changes often. As you rightly point out, flash memory might have some issues with that. Can you provide a little more context or detail as to what it is you are trying to do and why?

Comment: I want to save data in non-volatile memory.  The non-volatile memory that I have is flash.  Non-volatile is important because the product could be turned off for a period of time and I don't want to lose the data.  When the power comes back on, it needs to put the next piece of data after the last one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**First, block management:**

Put a smaller header at the start of each block. The main thing you need to keep track of the "oldest" and "newest" is a block number, which simply increments modulo **k**. **k** must be greater than your total number of blocks. Ideally, make **k** less than your MAX value (e.g. 0xFFFF) so you can easily tell what is an erased block.

At start-up, your code reads the headers of each block in turn, and locates the first and last blocks in the sequence that is n<sub>i+1</sub> = (n<sub>i</sub> + 1) MODULO k. Take care not to get confused by erased blocks (block number is e.g. 0xFFFF) or data that is somehow corrupted (e.g. incomplete erase).

**Within each block**

Each block initially starts empty (each byte is 0xFF). Each record is simply written one after the other. If you have fixed-size records, then you can access it with a simple index. If you have variable-size records, then to read it you have to scan from the start of the block, linked-list style.

If you want to have variable-size records, but avoid linear scan, then you could have a well defined header on each record. E.g. use 0 as a record delimiter, and [COBS](http://www.stuartcheshire.org/papers/COBSforToN.pdf)-encode (or [COBS/R](http://packages.python.org/cobs/cobsr-intro.html)-encode) each record. Or use a byte of your choice as a delimiter, and 'escape' that byte if it occurs in each record (similar to the [PPP protocol](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957975.aspx)).

At start-up, once you know your latest block, you can do a linear scan for the latest record. Or if you have fixed-size records or record delimiters, you could do a binary search.

**Erase scheduling**

For some Flash memory chips, erasing a block can take significant time--e.g. 5 seconds. Consider scheduling an erase as a background task a bit "ahead of time". E.g. when the current block is x% full, then start erasing the next block.

**Record numbering**

You may want to number records. The way I've done it in the past is to put, in the header of each block, the record number of the first record. Then the software has to keep count of the numbers of each record within the block.

**Checksum or CRC**

If you want to detect corrupted data (e.g. incomplete writes or erases due to unexpected power failure), then you can add a checksum or CRC to each record, and perhaps to the block header. Note the block header CRC would only cover the header itself, not the records, since it could not be re-written when each new record is written.

Comment: Hello Craig McQueen, please could you look at my question regarding circular buffer in flash [Circular buffer in flash implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54003995/circular-buffer-in-flash-implementation)

Answer (score 2):

Keep a separate block that contains a pointer to the start of the first record and the end of the last record.  You can also keep more information like the total number of records, etc.

Until you initially run out of space, adding records is as simple as writing them to the end of the buffer and updating the tail pointer.

As you need to reclaim space, delete enough records so that you can fit your current record.  Update the head pointer as you delete records.

You'll need to keep track of how much extra space has been freed.  If you keep a pointer to end of the last record, the next time you need to add a record, you can compare that with the pointer to the first record to determine if you need to delete any more records.

Also, if this is NAND, you or the flash controller will need to do deblocking and wear-leveling, but that should all be at a lower layer than allocating space for the circular buffer.

Comment: The block that contains the pointer to the first and last record will wear out more quickly than those containing the records since it needs to be updated each time a new record is written. For some flash memory with low write cycles this could occur as early as the 100,000th record.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get it now. It seems like your largest issue will be, having filled the available space for recording, what happens next? The new data should overwrite the oldest data, which is I believe what you mean by a circular buffer. But since the data is not fixed length you may overwrite more than one record.

I'm assuming that the amount of variability in length is high enough that padding everything out to a fixed length isn't an option.

Your write segment needs to keep track of the address that represents the start of the next record to write. If you know the size of a block to write ahead of time, you can tell if you are going to end up at the end of the logical buffer and start over at '0'. I wouldn't split a record up with some at the end and some at the beginning.

A separate register can track the beginning; this is the oldest data that hasn't been overwritten yet. If you went to read out the data this is where you would start.

The data writer then would check, given the write-start address and the length of data its about to commit, if it should bump the read register, which would examine the first block and see the length, and advance to the next record, until there is enough room to write whatever the data is. There will be a gap of junk data that lives between the end of the written data and the start of the oldest data, probably. But this way, you can just be writing an address or two as overhead, and not rearranging blocks.

At least, that's probably what I would do. HTH

Answer (score 1):

The "circular" in a flash can be done on basis of block size, which means that you must declare how much blocks of the flash you allocate for this buffer.

The actual size of the buffer will be at each particular time between n-1 (n is the number of blocks) and n.

Each block should start with an header that contains sequential number or timestamp that could be used to determine which block is older than the other.

Each Item encapsulated with an header and a footer. the default header contains whatever you want but according to this header you must know the size of the item. The default footer is 0xFFFFFFFF. This value indicates a null termination.

In your RAM you must save a pointer to the oldest block and the latest block and pointer to the oldest item and latest item. On power up you go over all blocks find the relevant blocks and load this members.

When you want to store a new item, you check if the latest block contain enough space for this item. If it does you save the item at the end of the previous item and the change the previous footer to point to this item. If it does not contain enough space you need to erase the oldest block. Before you erase this block change the oldest block members (RAM) to point on the next block and the oldest item to point on the first item in this block.
Then you can save the new item in this block and change the footer of the latest item to point this item.

I know that the explanation may sounds complicated but the process is very simple and if you write it correct you can make it even power fail safe (always keep in you mind the order of the writes).

Pay attention that the circularity of the buffer is not saved in the flash but the flash only contains a blocks with items that you can decide according to the blocks headers and items headers what is the order of these items

Answer (score 0):

I see three options:

option1: is to pad everything out to the same size, this is simple, store a pointer to the head and tail of the buffer so you know where to write and where to start reading from, use the size of each object to get an offset to the next, this means you need to transverse the buffer as you would a linked list, aka its slow if you need item 5000.

option2: is to store only pointers to the real data in the circular buffer, that way when you loop around you don't have to deal with size mis-matchs. if you store the real data in a circular buffer and don't pad it out you could run into a situations where your over witting multiple items with 1 new data object, i assume this is not ok.

store the actual data elsewhere in flash, most flash will have some sort of wear leveling built in, if so you don't need to worry about overwriting the same location multiple times, the IC will figure out where to actually store it on chip, just write to to the next available free space.

this means you need to pick a maximum size for the circular buffer how you do this depends on the data variability.  If the size of the data just change much, say by only a few bytes, then you should just pad it out and use option 1.  If the size changes wildly and unpredictably, choose the largest size it could be and figure out how many objects of that size would fit in your flash, use that as the max number of entries in the buffer.  This means you waste a bunch of space.

option 3: if the object can really be any size, your at the point where you should just use a file system, name the files in order and loop back when your full keeping in mind if your new entry is large you may have to delete multiple old entries to fit it in.  This is really just an extension of option 2 as option2 is in many ways a simple file system.

Comment: Be careful about the wear leveling assumption...True if you have USB or SD type interface. Not so true if you deal with the flash part directly.